# Multiple values in column to build data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query where I am using CTEs. In one of the CTEs, I am trying to get 3 values from the column where lots of values reside. Each of the 3 values needs to return the actual value and into a new column for each. If you look at `CTE_SPC` I look into column `ef.folder_type_name` for 'Site', 'Protocol', 'Country'.

The data rows are built off the `ef.entity_folder_id`. Every row will have these three pieces of data among a few others.

I am stuck figuring out how to effectively connect those three pieces of data with the others.

Not sure if I explained that well enough so if some clarification is needed, please ask.

```
WITH CTE_A AS 
(
    SELECT
       a.status AS status
       , a.entity_folder_id
       , a.activity_comment
       , a.id
       , a.activity__dt
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY a.entity_folder_id ORDER BY a.activity__dt DESC) AS ActivityRank
    --, ef.entity_folder_id
      , ef.folder_id
  FROM 
      activity a
  JOIN 
      entity_folder ef ON ef.folder_id = a.entity_folder_id
  WHERE 
      ef.deleted <> 1
), CTE_SCD AS 
(
    SELECT 
        CA.status
        , CA.activity_comment
        , CA.activity__dt
        , CA.entity_folder_id
        , CA.ActivityRank
        , CA.id
        , CA.folder_id
        --, ef.entity_folder_id
    FROM 
        CTE_A CA
    --JOIN entity_folder ef ON CA.entity_folder_id = ef.folder_id
    WHERE 
        CA.ActivityRank = 1
        AND CA.entity_folder_id = CA.folder_id
), CTE_SPC AS 
(
    SELECT 
        --ef.entity_name
        CASE 
            WHEN a.entity_folder_id = ef.folder_id AND ef.folder_type_name = 'Site' 
               THEN ef.entity_name 
        END AS 'Site'
        --, CASE WHEN ef.folder_type_name = 'Protocol' THEN ef.entity_name END AS 'Protocol'
        --, CASE WHEN ef.folder_type_name = 'MasterCountry' THEN ef.entity_name END AS 'Country'
    FROM 
        entity_folder ef
    JOIN 
        activity a ON a.entity_folder_id = ef.folder_id
)
```

Comment: The condition in the `case` matches the join condition to `activity` which makes it redundant, right? I'm thinking this is probably a pivot and you needs a `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with shawnt00's comment. A solution following his advice would look like this

```
...
CTE_SPC AS 
(
    SELECT 
        --ef.entity_name
        MAX(CASE WHEN ef.folder_type_name = 'Site' THEN ef.entity_name 
        END) AS 'Site',
        MAX(CASE WHEN ef.folder_type_name = 'Protocol' THEN ef.entity_name END) AS 'Protocol',
        MAX(CASE WHEN ef.folder_type_name = 'MasterCountry' THEN ef.entity_name END) AS 'Country'
    FROM 
        entity_folder ef
    JOIN 
        activity a ON a.entity_folder_id = ef.folder_id
    GROUP BY ef.folder_id
)
```

Your clause "... where lots of values reside" makes me also believe that this is essentially a pivot table. Correct me if it isn't.

To collect the values I used `MAX()` here, assuming, that an `ef.entity_name` for each `ef.folder_type_name` only occurs once. Otherwise you could of course also use `SUM()` or `MIN()` depending on what you really want.